# JavaScript Query and Projection Library

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking for some syntax or a library that will help me query JavaScript objects and Project the results similar to what can be achieved in C# LINQ.

For example:

```
{
    name: 'House',
    rooms: [{
        name: 'Bedroom',
        items: [{
             id: 1,
             name: 'Bed'
        }, {
             id: 2,
             name: 'Chair'
        }, {
             id: 3,
             name: 'Lamp'
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Bathroom',
        items: [{
             id: 4,
             name: 'Bath'
        }, {
             id: 5,
             name: 'Shower'
        }, {
             id: 6,
             name: 'Cupboard'
        }]
    }]
}
```

I want to say look in all rooms in the House and find me the item with an id of 2 and return me this object only.

So the result would be

```
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Chair'
}
```

Any advice on the best library and what syntax I would use to achieve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just use Array.find method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library recommendations are specifically off-topic for SO, but you've also asked for "syntax," so:

A simple loop through the `rooms` array's entries using `Array.prototype.find` on the `items` is all that's required:

```
function findItem(data, id) {
  let found = null;
  data.rooms.some(room => {
    found = room.items.find(item => item.id == id);
    return found != null;
  });
  return found;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const data = {
    name: 'House',
    rooms: [{
        name: 'Bedroom',
        items: [{
             id: 1,
             name: 'Bed'
        }, {
             id: 2,
             name: 'Chair'
        }, {
             id: 3,
             name: 'Lamp'
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Bathroom',
        items: [{
             id: 4,
             name: 'Bath'
        }, {
             id: 5,
             name: 'Shower'
        }, {
             id: 6,
             name: 'Cupboard'
        }]
    }]
};

function findItem(data, id) {
  let found = null;
  data.rooms.some(room => {
    found = room.items.find(item => item.id == id);
    return found != null; // Or `return !!found;`
  });
  return found;
}

console.log(findItem(data, 2));
```

That uses [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to loop through the entries in `rooms` until we find something, and within its callback, uses [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the item with the matching `id` value.

It can also be written a bit more concisely, perhaps sacrificing clarity:

```
function findItem(data, id) {
  let found = null;
  data.rooms.some(room => !!(found = room.items.find(item => item.id == id)));
  return found;
}
```

---

The above uses ES2015+'s arrow functions. If you can't use ES2015 features yet, here's the ES5 version:

```
function findItem(data, id) {
  var found = null;
  data.rooms.some(function(room) {
    found = room.items.find(function(item) { return item.id == id; });
    return found != null;
  });
  return found;
}
```